# What are the differences between the different words for mammoth? 猛犸和毛象有什么区别？

Tags: word-choice

I often pick up relatively esoteric animal names, and I got looking at mammoths one day... I found two words for mammoth: 猛犸 and 毛象. What is the difference between these two words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same, just translated in different ways.

1. `猛犸` is a transliteration. `猛` means robust dog. 《说文解字》: 猛，健犬也。 `犸` seems a more modern character, only used here.
2. `长毛象` is more common than `毛象`. The literal translation is "elephant with long hair".